# `onDidChangeTextDocument` not triggering after `applyEdit`

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VS Code extension for editing text files, and based my project off the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) and [Cat Customs example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/custom-editor-sample).

I currently have a [minimal working example](https://github.com/adamerose/markdown-editor) that uses a `contenteditable` div as a text editor to edit *.txt files. Similar to the Cat Customs sample, I use a `CustomTextEditorProvider` that connects to a Webview containing the editor, and use `postMessage` to update the document when the Webview text is changed, and then refresh the Webview to match the document if the document is saved. I am also logging occurrences of `onDidChangeTextDocument` which demonstrates my problem...

My problem is that if I type characters in the editor very quickly, my Webview sends a `postMessage` for every character and each triggers a corresponding `applyEdit` call, but many of these `applyEdit` calls don't seem to actually update the document model. I see the `onDidChangeTextDocument` event doesn't occur for many of them, and when I hit Ctrl+S to save my document it is missing updates from the latest `applyEdit` calls.

These are the two files that define everything I described above:
`CustomTextEditorProvider` : https://github.com/adamerose/markdown-editor/blob/master/src/textEditor.ts
`Webview`: https://github.com/adamerose/markdown-editor/blob/master/media/textEditorInitScript.js

Video example: https://www.screencast.com/t/tDa1XtqoUAyj
*I type `asdf` slowly and it works fine, then I type `4321` very quickly and the last 2 characters don't trigger `onDidChangeTextDocument` so when I save it reverts to `43`*

Here are some related issues but still couldn't solve my problem after reading them:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111331
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48908